# Reading text file line by line in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, text-files

How to read a text file from Oracle SQL*plus?

If there is a way to read from a bat file and pass the variable as a single line of text file, and simultaneously called from SQL*plus sql file, this option is ok.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you try and give a sample of what you want please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Oracle External Tables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).

For example, you have next file:

```
$ cat employee.dat

smith   clerk       800
scott   analyst     3000
adams   clerk       1100
miller  clerk       1300
```

Create external table:

```
create table employees (
ename varchar2(10),
title varchar2(10),
salary number(8))
organization external(
type oracle_loader default directory work_dir
    access parameters (record delimited by new line fields(
        ename char(10), title char(10), salary char(8)))
location ('employee.dat'))
parallel
```

Now you can use this file as SQL-table:

```
select * from employees;
```

Comment: aye, external tables is generally the simples way to go about it

Answer (score 0):

If the list is already comma separated in the test file, then you can
probably do something as simple as this in SQL*Plus ...

get id.txt
append )
0 select * from my_table where id in (
/